# Get the Ace editor content using PHP

Tags: php, web, editor

Hey guys I was wondering if it's possible to get the content within the  tags I have using PHP. I'm using the Ace editor and I have a save button. I'm trying to save the content to a file using PHP, can someone tell me how I can get the content using PHP please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you can save it via AJAX, 
send the editor content and desired filename (and path also) using POST method

example

```
function saveCode () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {code: editor.getValue(), filename: './test.php'},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log("success");
    });
}
```

then on the handler.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['code']))
    {
        file_put_contents($_POST['filename'], $_POST['code']);
        echo 'success';
    }

?>
```